# Placement of a 5" hole in foundation

Tags: foundation, drill, chimney

I have some concerns over where to place a 5" hole for a pellet stove chimney. The stove is in our basement, and I'd like to have the chimney exit through the exposed part of the foundation.

I have some wiggle room outside; The chimney needs to be at least 12 inches from the ground, and the foundation's top is 25.5" from the ground.

Ideally, though, the chimney would be as high as possible from the ground.

Here is a picture of the ideal placement as far as the chimney is concerned:[image]

Though the picture doesn't show it, the hole's left edge is perfectly in line with the "main beam's" right side (sorry don't know what it's actually called). That is to say that the big wooden beam supporting all my floor joists won't be directly above the hole, at any point, although it will be vertically *right next to it*.

I am just curious if I should be worried about the load of the "main beam" over a, I assume, weakened part of the foundation. As I mentioned, I could bring the chimney a little lower though I'd really rather not.

Here are some extra pictures:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that a concrete beam on the left side? How far does it span?

Comment: Not sure what your referring to. There's a piece of isofoil on the left... The only concrete is the wall

Comment: Clearly where the “M” (in the word “Main”) is on the picture, the concrete is different. You use the term “Beam”. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Ohh yes sorry. That's a painted metal plate, sort of a decorative cover for a chimney that's just outside the picture (if you are referring to to above the M, if not, that's the foil side of the isofoil. The foundation wall is the same all around the house, no concrete beams or pillars or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear to me what is a “Beam” in the picture...or if there is a concrete beam.

The reason it’s important is because the structural reinforcement steel could be going right through where the 5” hole is marked. If there’s no beam, then the hole can go where it’s marked.

I’d stay down 4” or so from the top so you’ll miss the top horizontal layer of reinforcement steel and 4” or so from the right side so that you’ll miss the last vertical reinforcement steel in the wall.

However, if there’s a concrete beam attached to this wall the reinforcement steel could be “trussed” up and into the area where the 5” hole is marked.

Comment: I think I see what you were talking about. Initially, I didn't see any difference in the concrete. I've added some more photos. I'm assuming you are referring to the vertical span of concrete that looks like it was poured separate from the rest?

Comment: PS when I say "main beam" I am referring to the large span of wood from one end of the house to the other onto which all the floor joists are attached.